# Magento 2 How to hide products from entire shop based on custom attribute value

Tags: magento2, products, custom-attributes, magento-2.2.5

Is there any way by custom code or plugin, products can be hide from entire frontend shop based on custom attribute type yes or no ?

Answer (score 2):

The Magento standard way would be to use the visibility attribute but if you have to do it with a custom attribute here's something that'll get you started, and may be all you need.

There isn't one function that can overridden to completely control product visibility but this is a good way to control the visibility of products on category pages.

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter">
        <plugin name="vendorname_modulename_catalog_model_layer_category_collectionfilter" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\CollectionFilter"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin/CollectionFilter.php

```
<?php

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin;

class CollectionFilter
{
    public function afterFilter(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\FullText\Collection $collection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
    ) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', 'custom_value');
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, Media Lounge, Please share the detail code packages.

Comment: I used your code, but it does not work.

Comment: Can you please provide the full module codes here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After fixing error about the above solution, I could find the solution.

The proper solution is as follow.

etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter">
    <plugin name="vendorname_modulename_catalog_model_layer_category_collectionfilter" type="Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin\CollectionFilter"/>
</type>
```

app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Plugin/CollectionFilter

```
 namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Plugin;

 class CollectionFilter
 {
    public function afterFilter(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter $subject,
        $result,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
    ) {
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('custom_attribute', $custom_value);
    }
 }
```

The plugin's parameters must be $subject, $result and same parameters of Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter's filter().

we can find it on vendor\magento\module-catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter.php

```
/**
 * Filter product collection
 *
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
 * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
 * @return void
 */
public function filter(
    $collection,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category $category
) {
    $collection
        ->addAttributeToSelect($this->catalogConfig->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addFinalPrice()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addUrlRewrite($category->getId())
        ->setVisibility($this->productVisibility->getVisibleInCatalogIds());
}
```

That's why the 3rd parameter must be as follow.

```
 \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $collection
```

Answer (score 0):

The above method works, but it results in the page navigation being off.

For example, if you are viewing 12 items per page with a total of 24 results, and hide one item on the first page, the first page should show a total of 12.  With this change, there will only be 11 items on the first page.